# Is this way of integrating correct?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, bounds-of-integration

I came across this integration in a paper and I'm a bit unsure about if it is correct or not.

This is an integral in cylindrical polar co-ordinates. The integration is over the entire volume of space (no bounds). The integration was done as follows:

$$\iiint \,f(z)\,g(r)\, r\,dr\,d\theta\, dz$$

$$= \iint  \,g(r) \, r\, dr\,d\theta\, \int_{-r}^r\,f(z)\,dz$$

$$ = \iint \,g(r)\, F(r)\,r\,dr\,d\theta\,$$

where $F(r) = \int_{-r}^r dz \,f(z)$

Now to me this seems just wrong. I would like a second opinion on this, as the paper was published in a reputed journal.

Comment: For future formatting reference, you should put your integrands in front of your differentials unless there is a very good reason not to. The exact limits may or may not be helpful as well, or at least the region we are integrating over.

Comment: As it is written, I think I'm just as confused as you are. Are you sure there's not addition bound on the space?

Comment: @Valborg : Good point. Corrected.

Comment: If this is indeed what was written in the paper, I think something has gone horribly wrong. We can't have the limits of $z$ depending on an inner variable, and we most certainly cannot bring that function back inside the $r$ integral.

Comment: Oh, of course they are physicists.

Comment: hehe, so am I. Perhaps I misunderstood their derivation?

Comment: The problem is that I am not so good at translating those integrals back into what I like looking at. I think you are now officially beyond my ability to help. And don't tell anyone, but I minored in physics!

Comment: @JackyChong Please see the paper referenced in my comment (sixth comment)

Comment: @Valborg I can understand that. And don't worry, your secret is safe with me!

Comment: I checked. They are correct.

Comment: @JackyChong Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
&\int^\infty_{-\infty} ds \int d^3\vec{k}\ |\rho_{|\vec{k}|}|^2 e^{-i(\Omega+\omega_{|\vec{k}|}\cosh\beta -k_3\sinh\beta) s} \\
= {} & \int^\infty_{-\infty} ds \int^\infty_0 dK \int_{|\vec{k}|=K} d\sigma\ |\rho_{|\vec{k}|}|^2e^{-i(\Omega+\omega_{|\vec{k}|}\cosh\beta -k_3\sinh\beta) s}\\
= {} & \int^\infty_{-\infty}ds \int^\infty_0 dK\ |\rho_K|^2 e^{-i(\Omega+\omega_{K}\cosh\beta)s} \int_{|\vec{k}|=K} d\sigma\ e^{ik_3\sinh \beta s} \\
= {} & \int^\infty_{-\infty}ds \int^\infty_0 dK\ |\rho_K|^2 e^{-i(\Omega+\omega_{K}\cosh\beta)s} \int_{|\vec{k}|=K} d\sigma\ \frac{\partial_{k_3}e^{ik_3\sinh \beta s}}{i\sinh \beta\ s} \\
= {} & \frac{1}{\sinh \beta} \int^\infty_{-\infty}ds \int^\infty_0 dK\ |\rho_K|^2 \frac{e^{-i(\Omega+\omega_{K}\cosh\beta)s}}{is} \int^K_{-K} dk_3\ \frac{K}{\sqrt{K^2-k_3^2}} \int_{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}=\sqrt{K^2-k_3^2}}dS\ \partial_{k_3}e^{ik_3\sinh \beta\ s}\\
= {} & \frac{2\pi}{\sinh \beta} \int^\infty_{-\infty}ds \int^\infty_0 dK\ |\rho_K|^2K \frac{e^{-i(\Omega+\omega_{K}\cosh\beta)s}}{is} \int^K_{-K} dk_3\ \partial_{k_3}e^{ik_3\sinh \beta\ s}  
\end{align}

Hence we get 
\begin{align}
&\frac{2\pi}{\sinh \beta} \int^\infty_{-\infty}ds \int^\infty_0 dK\ |\rho_K|^2K \frac{e^{-i(\Omega+\omega_{K}\cosh\beta)s}}{is} \int^K_{-K} dk_3\ \partial_{k_3}e^{ik_3\sinh \beta\ s} \\
&=\ \frac{4\pi}{\sinh\beta} \int^\infty_{-\infty} ds \int^\infty_0 dK\ |\rho_K|^2K e^{-i(\Omega+\omega_{K}\cosh\beta)s} \frac{\sin(K\sinh\beta s)}{s}.
\end{align}

I hope this helps.

Additional Info: Consider the sphere of radius $K$ (fixed radius), say $x^2+y^2+z^2 = K^2$, then
\begin{align}
\text{ Surface Area of the Sphere} =\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2=K^2}d\sigma = \int^K_{-K} \frac{K}{\sqrt{K^2-z^2}}dz\int_{x^2+y^2=K^2-z^2} dS
\end{align}
where $dS$ is the measure on the circle. Now, for each fixed $z$, we see that
\begin{align}
\int_{x^2+y^2= K^2-z^2} dS = \text{ Circumference of a circle of radius } \sqrt{K^2-z^2}
\end{align}
which is just $2\pi \sqrt{K^2-z^2}$. Thus, it follows 
\begin{align}
\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2=K^2}d\sigma = 2\pi \int^K_{-K} \frac{K}{\sqrt{K^2-z^2}}dz\ \sqrt{K^2-z^2}  = 2\pi \int^K_{-K} = 4\pi K^2.
\end{align}

Note: I have used the [Co-area formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_coarea_formula) for smooth manifold.

Comment: This looks useful. What is $\sigma$ here though?

Comment: Surface measure of the sphere of radius $K$.

Comment: Are you taking $K = \sqrt{k_1^2 +k_2^2 +k_3^2}$ as they've taken or $\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}$

Comment: $K = \sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2+k_3^2}$

Comment: I don't understand the step going from $d\sigma$ to $dk_3 $ integral. I suppose $d\sigma = ksin^2 \theta d\theta d\phi$?

Comment: Consider the sphere with radius $K$. We will integrate vertically (so not spherical coordinates) from height $k_3 = K$ to $k_3 = -K$.

Comment: Right. But then the remaining integral should be on $dk_1dk_2$ and not $dK$?

Comment: Are you saying $dk_1dk_2 = \sqrt{K^2-k_3^2}dK$?

Comment: I don't understand. First I don't understand which co-ordinate system is being used. It's not spherical polar if you are using $k_3$. It can't be cylindrical either if you're using $dK$. Second, I don't understand how one can integrate over $k_3$ while keeping $K$ fixed because if $k_3$ varies so does $K$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45895/discussion-between-nirmalya-kajuri-and-jacky-chong).

Answer (score 0):

I think it must have been intended to be read like this:

$$\iiint f(z)\,g(r)\, r\,dr\,d\theta\, dz = \iint \left( g(r) \, r\, dr\,d\theta\, \int_{-r}^r f(z)\,dz \right)$$

Thus the integral $\displaystyle \int_{-r}^r$ is inside the integral with respect to $r$, even though it's written to the right of $dr$.

Comment: That's not the problematic part. The last step is the problematic part - where the outer integral is pulled back in.

Comment: Please see the original question. It's not put back as a constant but as a function of x and further integrated. I can think of examples where that would be wrong. I'm a tad unsure if the case considered in the paper is somehow different.

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri : I've completely revised this answer. $\qquad$